# Is rosdoc supposed to be working in groovy with catkin pakages?

Tags: ros, rosdoc, ros-groovy, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is rosdoc supposed to be working in groovy with catkin pakages? I tried to use it but got meesages like:

```
WARN: Package 'lrs_msgs' does not have a valid manifest.xml file, manifest information will not be included in docs
```

But catkin packages does not have a manifest.xml file.

Or should I generate the documentation in some other way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53813/is-rosdoc-supposed-to-be-working-in-groovy-with-catkin-pakages?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosdoc has been replaced by [rosdoc_lite](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdoc_lite), which is automatically run for packages in repositories that have rosinstall files listed in the [rosdisto](http://ros.org/wiki/rosdistro) repository.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-01-31**:
I want to generate private documentation. I cannot find rosdoc_lite in my groovy installation. So how am I supposed to install it?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-31**:
Please ask that as a separate question, so others can find it in the future.

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-01-31**:
Now asked as a separate question.